# duplicate entry in android studio when using appboy sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, appboy

I am searching in this issue from a lot of time

when I try to run my app on any device I got the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':_4SaleApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bo/app/a.class
```

I have tried many options to solve it, but none of them work with me

finally I run the following terminal command

```
gradlew -q app:dependencies
```

then I found the following

```
+--- com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 -> 23.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.appboy:android-sdk-jar:1.11.2
```

I don't know why appboy include `23.0.1 -> 23.1.0 (*)`

can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in your gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and it exclude all of them, while I need it in some libraries

Comment: compile('com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.2') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
} as mentioned in the answer by BOUTERBIAT

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle` do the following :

```
compile('com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.2') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}
```

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project too

Comment: I did, and still facing the same problem